# In Catalina, Can Fingerprint Replace Password Requests on Preference

Tags: password, catalina, preferences

I am running 10.15.2 in a MacBook Pro15,1 (6-core, I7) and I was curious if the fact that you **cannot** use fingerprint authentication to gain access top Settings panel is by design or if this is a "personal problem". I am able to use it for the other typical uses such as in Safari or the App Store, but it is tedious that you need to type your password whenever you wish to make preference edits.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can replace a password request on System Preference with Fingerprint also.

You can also use Touch ID to unlock these features on your Mac:

•   Password-protected Notes

•   The Passwords section in Safari 
preferences

•   System Preferences

**Note**: If you have FileVault turned on, you must type your password to unlock the Security & Privacy pane and the Users & Groups pane.

•   Just make sure that you have enabled all the checkboxes to select the Touch ID features that you want to use on your Mac.